# Why is my summarize function not working for certain years?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my first time using R so I was given a starter code for the project. The summary function that was provided for the year 2000 is:

```r
summaries <- data_south_west %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`))
```

I copied the function as instructed and edited the function:

```r
summarize(mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
```

Why is the year 2000 findable, but 2005 isn't?

[image: Image of the entire function]
[image: Image of the source of data]

Comment: While some code is able to handle column names like `2005` it is almost always better to simply rename your columns to e.g. `Y2005`. Then you don't have to worry about these problems.

Comment: You have two good answers that explain your problem and its solution.  But in future, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you code is syntactically wrong. First, to replicate your issue I use some random example data:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Random example data
set.seed(123)

data_south_west <- data.frame(
  Region = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  "2000" = runif(100),
  "2005" = runif(100),
  check.names = FALSE
)
```

Next, running your code I get the same error you mentioned.

```
data_south_west %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Region mean00  sd00 median00 iqr00
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.492 0.261    0.467 0.427
#> 2 B       0.543 0.268    0.572 0.391
  summarize(mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
#> Error in mean(`2005`): object '2005' not found
```

The reason is that to connect multiple `summarise` or other `dplyr` verbs you have to make use of the pipe operator `%>%` to pipe the result from one statement into the next. However, in your case simply piping will not fix the issue because after summarizing the result is a `dataframe` or `tibble` which no longer has a column named `2005`.

Instead, if you want to `summarise` multiple columns you have to do so in one `summarise` call, i.e. do:

```r
data_south_west %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`),
            mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>   Region mean00  sd00 median00 iqr00 mean05  sd05 median05 iqr05
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.492 0.261    0.467 0.427  0.492 0.287    0.503 0.486
#> 2 B       0.543 0.268    0.572 0.391  0.478 0.307    0.472 0.536
```

However, a less verbose approach to achieve the same result would be to use `dplyr::across` which allows to apply the same set of functions to multiple data columns. Here I make use of the `.name` argument to name the columns after summarizing according to your example code.

```
data_south_west %>% 
  group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(`2000`, `2005`), 
                   .fns = list(mean = mean, sd = sd, median = median, iqr = IQR),
                   .names = "{.fn}{substr(.col, 3, 4)}"
  ))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 9
#>   Region mean00  sd00 median00 iqr00 mean05  sd05 median05 iqr05
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.492 0.261    0.467 0.427  0.492 0.287    0.503 0.486
#> 2 B       0.543 0.268    0.572 0.391  0.478 0.307    0.472 0.536
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first command works while the second doesn't, because you didn't feed any data into `summarize()` in the second command.

The first example may span two lines, but it is one command:

```
summaries <- data_south_west %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`))
```

The different parts of the command are connected through the assignment operator `<-` and through pipes `%>%`.

##### Pipes in R

What a pipe does, is take the output from the code on one of its sides, and provide it as the first argument for the code on the other side. In the case of the `%>%` pipe, it takes the output from the left, and provides it as the first argument to the code on the right.

Try running the following example:

```
"hello" %>% paste("world") %>% print()
```

It is essentially the same code as `print(paste("hello", "world")`.

The great benefit of using pipes is that you can use them to chain commands one after another, instead of inside of each other. This makes long commands easier to read, more intuitive to interpret (the computer executes them left to right instead of inside to outside), and easier to edit.

The [`%>%`](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) pipe comes from the `magrittr` package, and is what you'll see in use the most right now. Base R also introduced a pipe recently: since 4.1+ you can use [`|>`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/).

##### Back to Question

###### Explaining the working code

In this code:

```
summaries <- data_south_west %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarize(mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`))
```

the first pipe takes the contents of `data_south_west`, feeds them into `group_by()` as its first argument, which then becomes `group_by(data_south_west, Region)`.

The second pipe takes the result from `group_by()` and feeds it into `summarize()`, which becomes:

```
summarize(<the_result_of_group_by>, mean00 = mean(`2000`), sd00 = sd(`2000`), median00 = median(`2000`), iqr00 = IQR(`2000`))
```

Finally after `summarize()` is done, the result of that is put into `summaries` by `<-`.

###### Error

The following code:

```
summarize(mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
```

is different from the working code, as the first argument is lacking. You can either provide it in place, or through a pipe:

```
summarize(data_south_west, mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
```

```
data_south_west %>% summarize( mean05 = mean(`2005`), sd05 = sd(`2005`), median05 = median(`2005`), iqr05 = IQR(`2005`))
```